# The modifier 'XXXX' is not valid for this item

Tags: c#, static

Does anyone have an idea why I get these errors:

> The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item
>
> The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item

on line 3 of the following code:

```
public class YYY
{
    private static readonly struct ZZZ
    {
        private int x = 0;
        private int y = 0;
        private int z = 0;
    }
}
```

When I researched the matter, I found answers only for Interfaces which I am not very aware of but I only want to create a static readonly struct field in my class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` and `readonly` are both modifiers only used in the implementation of an object, not in the definition. When you declare the `ZZZ` struct object you will be using, at that point you can add the modifiers `static` and `readonly`.

```
public class YYY
{
    private struct ZZZ
    {
        private int x = 0;
        private int y = 0;
        private int z = 0;
    }

    private static readonly ZZZ myZZZ = new ZZZ(); //The declaration of a ZZZ instance.
}
```